# Change component upon clicking a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner in react. Let's say there is a bell icon for notifications. Once clicked, there will be a summary of recently received notifications and below, there is a button. When I click that button, I want to replace the recent notifications component with a list containing past notifications without having the need to go to different pages. How can I implement the `onClick` handler on the initial button? Should I use `react-router`?

`Notif.jsx (recent notifs)`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';

export default function BasicMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        id="basic-button"
        aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <img className="icons" src="notif-icon.png" />
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="basic-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        MenuListProps={{
          'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
        }}
      >
        <Button variant="contained"> See all notifs </Button> *// once clicked, it will show the full list of notifs w/o redirecting to another page*
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>notif 1</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>notif 1</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>notif 1</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`FullList.jsx (Full history of notifs)`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import MenuList from '@mui/material/MenuList';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import ContentCut from '@mui/icons-material/ContentCut';
import ContentCopy from '@mui/icons-material/ContentCopy';
import ContentPaste from '@mui/icons-material/ContentPaste';
import Cloud from '@mui/icons-material/Cloud';

export default function IconMenu() {
  return (
    <Paper sx={{ width: 320, maxWidth: '100%' }}>
      <MenuList>
        <MenuItem>
          <ListItemText>notif 1</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>
          <ListItemText>notif 2</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>
          <ListItemText>notif 3</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>
          <ListItemText>notif 4</ListItemText>
        </MenuItem>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your question is too vague, but it sounds like you are wanting optional rendering or router rending. If you want router rendering then you need to set up react-router-dom to accept different routes and have the onClick handler of the button navigate to the new route. Otherwise use conditional routing such as {isClicked && <MyComponent />} where isClicked is set to true when you click the Button... Read up on handling onClick method and hooks/state.

Comment: I'm so sorry about the question. Yes I was wondering on how can I implement the conditional routing without redirecting to another page

Comment: Please see https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Comment: Question is still too vague. From what I have gathered you want to conditionally "expand"/"collapse" or show/hide the `MenuItem` components in the button in `BasicMenu`. What is the issue? Would an `Accordion` from MUI be useful for your use case here?

Comment: After clicking the button, I want the `Notif.jsx` and its contents to be hidden after clicking the `Button` so that the contents of `FullList.jsx` will be displayed.

Comment: How do these two components/files relate to each other? I don't see any relationship between them. It seems we need more context for what you are trying to accomplish. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese For this one, `Notif.jsx` will show the recent notifications of the system. There is a button wherein once clicked, `FullList.jsx` will be called and all of the past notifications will replace the content of `Notif.jsx`

Answer (score 0):

You can do optional rendering 3 different ways. You can either use conditoinal rendering using the && operator like this: `a && <B />` in this case if a is true, then B is rendered. 
You can also use a ternary operator `a ? <B /> : <C />` Which will render either B or C where a is true and false respectively
And you can use react-router-dom (or others) to route the entire window location to render a different page. 
Here I am going to assume you just want to conditionally render a notification list or just generally conditional rendering.
Suppose you have the following code.

```
function MyComponent(props) {//React functional component
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = React.useState(false); //Here I am using react hooks (since react 16).
    function handleClick(e) => {
        setIsClicked(true);
    }//We pass this function into the buttons onClick method
    return (
        <div>
            {!isCicked && <button id="notificationBtn" onClick={handleClick} />}
            {isClicked && <NotificationList />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

In this example the NotificationList is a component that has your notification code to list all notifications etc as you mentioned...
using the && operator will either render the componnt or it won't. Another way we could have written this code is using a ternary operator... It would have looked like this inside the div
`{!isClicked ? <button id="notificationBtn" onClick={handleClick} /> : <NotificationList />}`
Please note you do have to wrap any jsx that has more inner jsx appearing in parenthesis as you would normally do. Such as:
`{isClicked && (<div><span>Children</span><button>Click me</button></div>)}`

I hope this makes sense how we can take advantage of these 2 methods of conditional rendering (the one where we optionally render a component and the other where we render something or something else (ternary)).
If you would rather navigate the entire window (for flow control, etc) then react-router-dom is what you are looking for. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-react-router-dom/) is a tutorial on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks! But there was a problem, once I clicked the button, the elements (the recent notifs) aren't removed, is there a way to remove them so that the elements of the new component will be displayed?

Comment: @pat Could you share your code that way I understand exactly what the problem is??? As I mentioned the question is kind of vague, and I don't know what exactly you are talking about when you say recent notifs aren't removed... Thanks share the code and I will try to help you.

Comment: the code is now added for better explanation

Comment: Alright, again you didn't list which button you where clicking and apply my answer to your code and it will work just fine. Lets say for example you want an element <MyCustomList /> to be hidden when the "open" is true. Then you would have something like this {!open && (<MyCustomList />)} please note the curly braces "{" "}" as these are required. Again I don't quite know what you mean because you didn't state which button you were clicking, and nothing indicates what are "recent notifs" they are all just notifs.

Comment: The one with the `//` is the button that needed to be clicked in order for the `FullList.jsx` to be displayed. Can {isClicked} and {open} be together as a condition for the content of `FullList.jsx` to be displayed?